# Jquery for Mobile in a mobile website - Adsense Issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, adsense

I have adsense on a mobile website that uses jquery mobile. The problem that is coming is that it shows adsense ads only on the first page. When the user follows links from the fist page to other pages, then the same adsense code does not show till the page is manually refreshed.
I am using

```
data-ajax="false" target="_blank"
```

for the links. Still the code does not always show on the target pages. It shows when the pages are manually refreshed. I am using responsive ads.

The adsense javascript is inside

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="e">
```

Comment: Hi, Not a duplicate as this is something that is discussed in that issue but is behaving otherwise. The adsense content is fully inside the <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">